# How to send e-mails from custom PHP code?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to send an e-mail from my custom php code using the Drupal service.

In other words, I've noticed Drupal can easily send emails so I would like to know how can I use drupal libraries to send the emails, instead of using external libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [drupal_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_mail), and define [hook_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_mail/6) in your module.

You'll then call the first one, and the e-mail information will be set by the second one.
(See the example on the documentation page for `drupal_mail()`.)

Comment: if I have my php code in a script how do I invoke the correct hook. In other words, if I invoke drupal_mail(), how can I refer to the right hook_mail() ?

Comment: Read the documentation page Pascal referred to. Quote: `// example_mail() will be called based on the first drupal_mail() parameter.`

Answer (score 7):

```
$message = array(
  'to' => 'example@mailinator.com',
  'subject' => t('Example subject'),
  'body' => t('Example body'),
  'headers' => array('From' => 'example@mailinator.com'),
);

drupal_mail_send($message);
```

Caveats:

- Because `drupal_mail()` isn't called, other modules will not be able to `hook_mail_alter()` your output, which can cause unexpected results.
- `drupal_mail_send()` is ignorant about which language to send the message in, so this needs to be figured out beforehand.
- You'll have to manually specify any other e-mail headers that are required ('Content-Type', etc.). These are normally taken care of for you by `drupal_mail()`.
  In the case where your module sends several different types of emails, and you want those email templates to be editable (for example, user module's various registration notification/password reset/etc. e-mails), using `hook_mail()` is still the best way to go.

This is what reported in [a comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/198#comment-198) in the documentation for [drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/6). If the caveats are not important in your case, then you can use the reported snippet.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to use mimemail. It's a contrib module that will allow you to send HTML mails (+ attachments) or plaintext-only messages with ease. Here is an excerpt from the readme file:

the mimemail() function:

- $sender - a user object or email address
- $recipient - a user object or email address
- $subject - subject line
- $body - body text in html format
- $plaintext - boolean, whether to send messages in plaintext-only (default false)

This module creates a user preference for receiving plaintext-only messages. This preference will be honored by all calls to mimemail()

Link: http://drupal.org/project/mimemail

I hope this will help you!

Comment: thanks for this tip. Although the solution to the question was simply drupal_mail, I'm now using mimemail because I need to send attachments. Please check this my new question if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258760/drupal-mimemail-e-mails-without-attachment